# Export an executable Jar from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

What are the differences between those three options for Library handling while exporting an executable jar from Eclipse ?

which one is better and the generated jar executes faster?

I currently tried the first and second option, it seems like the firs one runs faster, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is simpler by adding dependency classes to the manifest classpath. Another option if you want to merge dependency classes to the one jar, which is executable, so you don't need other library dependencies to run the program. The better is one that better suits your needs. Faster or slower is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

None of them are actually "better".  It all depends on what you plan to do with or jar and what you want to do with the libraries.

1. Extract required libraries into generated JAR (I commonly use this)
   This will put all the libraries used with your project into the jar file. It will not keep them in jar form, but instead put the files for the libraries in a path of folders. If you use this and you have the same class path for your library and your project it may conflict. You can run the jar file from anywhere and the libraries will be apart of it.
2. Package required libraries into generated JAR will put the jar files for the libraries directly into the executable jar.
3. Copy required libaries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR will create a folder in the path to the jar file and put the libraries inside it.  If the JAR files is placed in another folder than the folder with the libraries then it will not find the libraries to run.

Here are some screen shots of each option:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]